# Ruby, Can't delete a specific line from string

Tags: ruby

I know that this topic is duplicated, But I swear I watched many videos on Youtube, And read many topics on Google and Stackoverflow to solve my problem! but in vain, All methods didn't work I don't know why.

I just want to delete a specific line

I used many functions to do it

```
        data.sub!(/Server:.*/, '')
```

and this

```
data.gsub('\n','')
```

The response from a local server was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GOV
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Language: en-US
```

I just want to remove this line     `Server: GOV`

I found this method by using this function `data.match`

```
    if data.match('Server')
        data.sub!(/Server:.*/, '')
    end
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Language: en-US
```

How can I let the output be like this without the empty line

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Language: en-US
```

Note: I lost more than 2 hours to solve this problem, And I still stuck with it, It wasted my time

Comment: Simply match the new line as part of the regex pattern being replaced. Aka `data.sub!(/Server:.*\n/, '')`.

Comment: @ndnenkov Thank you very much, You're number one! How Can I put tick on your answer?

Comment: It's a comment so you can't. But if you want to leave an official answer for future readers, you could post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: @ndnenkov You deserve it.